# Cannot get last child of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the last child of a `<div>` but I am failing. Here is the code that I use for it but it always returns `undefined`.

```
$('#output:last-child').attr('class');
```

What is wrong? How can I fix it?

This is supposed to be the last element:

```
<div class='hisout ${hisclass}'><p class="he">` + message + '</p></div>
```

Comment: Please show HTML source code.

Comment: what is the html? could be the last child doesn't have a class attribute.

Comment: Change it to `$("#output:last")`.

Comment: Using the `#` is for id, which should be unique. Is `output` a class or id in the elements' attributes?

Comment: @seantunwin output is parent div so it is id

Comment: there is not div with `id="output"`.. something like `<div id='output' class='hisout ${hisclass}'><p class="he">` + message + '</p></div>`

Comment: No 

`<div id="output"><div class='hisout ${hisclass}'><p class="he">` + message + '</p></div></div>`  like this

Comment: Your selector is saying find the element that has the id output and is the last child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the child combinator selector:
`$('#output > :last-child').attr('class');`

*Edit: Added example*

```css
#output > :last-child {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="output">
  <div>....</div>
  <div>....</div>
  <div>....</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is retrieving the `#output` element that **is** the last child of its parent.

From the description it sounds like you want to find the last child **within** `#output`, as such you need to separate the selectors:

```
$('#output div:last-child').attr('class');
```

Comment: What would that return for `<div id="output"><div class="foo"><div class="bar"></div></div></div>`?

Comment: i think it would return 'foo'

Comment: Probably not what the OP wants :) but they did specify their HTML in the question. @seantunwin's approach with the child selector would be more robust in that case

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  

in this code: 

`document.onfocus = () => {
   console.log($('#output div:last-child').attr('class'))
}`

it logs twice everytime and it returns undefined for first time when i send message via socket.io (socket.io). why?

Comment: There could be lots of reasons for that behaviour. I'd suggest starting a new question about it, including a full code example

Answer (score -2):

You can try with the [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) and [`last()`](https://api.jquery.com/last/) functions:

```
$('#output').children().last().attr('class')
```

To specifically filter a type of child, you can specify the type in the `children()` call:

```
...children('div')...
```

Using a selector may be faster, though.

Comment: `$.last()` returns the last element of the jQuery collection. For a jQuery selector selecting via `id` the collection will always have only one element. So no matter how many elements with `id="output"` the page has (as long as it's at least one), `$('#output').last() === $('#output')`  will be `true`.